# Trying to use jquery ui in google chrome extension in the content level

Tags: jquery-ui, google-chrome

The problem is that the scope of the content script is on the web page that your plugin is suppose to be used at.

So the css background:url(images/ui-bg_inset-hard_100_fcfdfd_1x100.png) becomes
url('http://webpageforplugin/images/ui-bg_inset-hard_100_fcfdfd_1x100.png')
in order for this to work as far as i understood i need to have it to point to:
url('chrome-extension://extensionId/images/ui-bg_inset-hard_100_fcfdfd_1x100.png')

So i tried to haxorz the document.styleSheets

```
var ss = document.styleSheets;

for (var i=0; i<ss.length; i++) {
    var found=-1, x,i;
    var rules = ss[i].cssRules || ss[i].rules;

    for (var j=0; j<rules.length; j++) {
        if ('.ui-helper-hidden'==rules[j].selectorText){
            found=i;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (found>-1){
        for (var j=0; j<rules.length; j++) {
            if (x=rules[j].style.background){
                if ((i=x.indexOf('url'))!=-1)
                    rules[j].style.background = x.replace('http://page/images/','chrome-extension://extensionId/images/');
            }
        }
        break;
    }   
};
```

I feel that i'm missing the obvious. That there must be an easier way.

Even if i manage to change this how will i get the extension id to build the string.

Btw this doesn't work, the icons are not properly fetched. (I hardcoded the extension id)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I currently have this: (jquery-ui-content.hack.js)

```
$(function(){
    function fixcsspath(rules, folder){
        var path_prefix = chrome.extension.getURL('');
        var lookfor = 'url(';
        var ss = document.styleSheets;

        for (var j=0; j<rules.length; j++) {
            var b = rules[j].style['background-image'];
            var s;
            if (b && (s = b.indexOf(lookfor)) >= 0 ){
                s = s + lookfor.length;
                rules[j].style['background-image'] = b.replace(b.substr(s,b.indexOf(folder)-s), path_prefix);
            }   
        }
    };

    var ss = document.styleSheets;

    for (var i=0; i<ss.length; i++) {
        var rules = ss[i].rules || ss[i].cssRules;
        if (rules[0].selectorText!="#chrome-extention-relative-paths")
            continue;
        fixcsspath(ss[i].rules, '/images/');
    }
});
```

And I just put this on the first line of every css that needs this

```
#chrome-extention-relative-paths {}
```

WARNING this only works for background-image urls which is all that is required for jquery ui

Comment: This seems like a great solution; only for me 
   var ss = document.styleSheets;
doesn't seem to contain the css I'm injecting in my manifest.json.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can reference your chrome extension ID in the CSS - see this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8864212/113855

Answer (score 0):

It seems I managed to get a preliminary solution to this problem although it is not the best one, it works ;-)

Basically, it consists on editing the jquery-ui-1.8.1.custom.css of the jQueryUI theme and substituting all the occurrences of the url() construction using relative paths with absolute online paths. As an example, subtitute "url(images/ui-bg_highlight-soft_100_eeeeee_1x100.png)" with "url(http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.8.1/themes/ui-lightness/images/ui-bg_highlight-soft_100_eeeeee_1x100.png)" using the files from the jQueryUI subversion site. As you can see, you only have to put "http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.8.1/themes/ui-lightness/" in front taking into account the concrete theme you are using or want to use ("ui-lightness" in this case).

In case I find a better solution, I'll let you know. Please, do the same ;-)

Best,

```
         Germán.
```

Comment: There is a small problem with this.
Your plugin cannot work offline.

Comment: It might be better to reference the files from the "official" CDN location - e.g. https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.11/themes/dark-hive/images/ui-bg_flat_50_5c5c5c_40x100.png