# Google Chrome Extensions - Can't load local images with CSS

Tags: css, google-chrome-extension, background-image

I have a simple Chrome extension that uses the content script feature to modify a website. More specifically, the `background-image` of said website.

For some reason I can't seem to be able to use local images, even though they are packed in the extension.

```
body {
    background: #000 url('image.jpg') !important;
    background-repeat: repeat !important;
}
```

That's it, the simplest CSS... but it won't work. The browser doesn't load the image.

Comment: Why would the extension think that url('image.jpg') is local? Wouldn't you need a full path?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Your image URL should look like `chrome-extension://<EXTENSION_ID>/image.jpg`

You would be better off replacing css through javascript. From [docs](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/dev/content_scripts.html):

```
//Code for displaying <extensionDir>/images/myimage.png:
var imgURL = chrome.extension.getURL("images/myimage.png");
document.getElementById("someImage").src = imgURL;
```

Comment: @Salem Because otherwise you would need to hardcode your extension id in css.

Comment: Not to be dumb, but why is that an issue?

Comment: @Salem It would be inconvenient to develop as unpacked extension id and uploaded to the gallery one have different ids. It's not the end of the world, just inconvenience and sort of bad practice, just like hardcoding absolute file pathes in the code for example.

Comment: Since this is the accepted answer, you should see comment on the other answer where ariera mentioned about including  web_accessible_resources in your manifest file to access local fonts and images.

Comment: `chrome.runtime.getURL` — the new API

Answer (score 280):

Chrome has [i18n support](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/i18n)  that provides the ability to reference your extension in your CSS. I keep my images in an image folder in the extension, so reference assets in the CSS like so:

```
background-image:url('chrome-extension://__MSG_@@extension_id__/images/main.png');
```

The image(s) must be listed in [web_accessible_resources](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/manifest/web_accessible_resources/) in manifest.json.

Comment: Great one. This is a great solution and does indeed work for both unpackaged and packaged extensions - thanks for sharing a really great tip.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for.

Just a footnote: remember that you need to declare your assets as web_accessible_resources in your manifest file (as explained here: http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/manifest.html#web_accessible_resources). Otherwise they won't be loaded

Comment: One thing i realized! Never think accepted answer is the only correct  solution for that question!
I was afraid i have to do hardcode when i saw accepted answer but after seeing you answer i told myself this guy saved my day!! ;-)

Comment: This is almost always the better way to do it.  Pure CSS vs. coupling Javascirpt and CSS together in @serg answer.  This should be the accepted answer in my opinion.

Comment: @ariera's link is here now: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources

Comment: If you struggle with chrome vs firefox: use this: `@supports(-webkit-user-select: none )
{
 :root{
  --url_header: url("chrome-extension://__MSG_@@extension_id__/images/header.gif");
 }
}

@supports(-moz-user-select: none )
{
 :root{
  --url_header: url("moz-extension://__MSG_@@extension_id__/images/header.gif");
 }
}`

Comment: this doesn't work for chrome 76, it can only work when I specify the real extension id, like: ```url(chrome-extension://fibcjgogcmhklkadjokijclpdcfmpdhp/resources/32px.png)```, rather than ```url(chrome-extension://__MSG_@@extension_id__/resources/32px.png)```, any idea?

Comment: @aaron Add images to `web_accessible_resources` in `manifest.json`

Answer (score 53):

There are a lot of older answers and solutions to this question.

As of August 2015 (using Chrome 45 and Manifest version 2), the current "best practice" for linking to local images within [Chrome Extensions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted) is the following approach.

1) Link to the asset in your CSS using a [relative path](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#relative-urls) to your extension's images folder:

```
.selector {
    background: url('chrome-extension://__MSG_@@extension_id__/images/file.png');
}
```

2) Add the individual asset to to the [web_accessible_resources](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources) section of your extension's **manifest.json** file:

```
"web_accessible_resources": [
  "images/file.png"
]
```

*Note: This method is suitable for a few files, but doesn't scale well with many files.*

Instead, a better method is to leverage Chrome's support for [match patterns](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns) to whitelist all files within a given directory:

```
{
    "name": "Example Chrome Extension",
    "version": "0.1",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    ...    
    "web_accessible_resources": [
      "images/*"
    ]
}
```

Using this approach will allow you to quickly and effortlessly use images in your Chrome Extension's CSS file using natively supported methods.

Comment: The syntax of ```web_accessible_resources``` has changed in manifest version 3. The answer is out of date but conceptually helpful.

Answer (score 25):

One option would be to [convert](http://www.motobit.com/util/base64-decoder-encoder.asp) your image to base64:

and then put the data right into your css like:

```
body { background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,iVB...); }
```

While this [might not be an approach you would want to use when regularly developing a webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1124149/embedding-background-image-data-into-css-as-base64-good-or-bad-practice), it is a great option due to some of the constraints of building a Chrome Extension.

Comment: I prefer this option.  I disagree that Google is correct to suggest injecting _all_ images via the approach mentioned above.  The base64 approach is also faster. +1!!!

Answer (score 22):

My solution.

With Menifest v2 you need to add `web_accessible_resources` to the file and then use `chrome-extension://__MSG_@@extension_id__/images/pattern.png` as the url in your css file.

**CSS:**

```
 #selector {
      background: #fff url('chrome-extension://__MSG_@@extension_id__/images/pattern.png'); 
 }
```

**Manifest.json**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "My Extension Name",
  "description": "My Description",
  "version": "1.0",

  "content_scripts": [
      {
        "matches": ["https://mydomain.com/*"],
        "css": ["style.css"]
      }
    ],

  "permissions": [
    "https://mydomain.com/"
  ],
  "browser_action": {
      "default_icon": {                    
            "19": "images/icon19.png",           
            "38": "images/icon38.png"          
       },
       "default_title": "My Extension Name"  
   },
   "web_accessible_resources": [
       "images/pattern.png"
     ]
}
```

p.s. Your manifest.json might look different to this one.

Answer (score 9):

This CSS-version-only works in **extension environment (app page, popup page, background page, option page)** as well as **content_scripts CSS file.**

In .less file, I always set a variable at the beginning:

```
@extensionId : ~"__MSG_@@extension_id__";
```

Then later, if you want to refer to extension-local-resource like images, use:

```
.close{
    background-image: url("chrome-extension://@{extensionId}/images/close.png");
}
```

Answer (score 9):

One thing to mention is that in the web_accessible_resources you can use wildcards.  So instead of

"images/pattern.png"

You can use

"images/*"

Answer (score 4):

Just to clarify, according to the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#relative-urls), every file in an extension is also accessible by an absolute URL like this:

> **chrome-extension://**`<extensionID>`**/**`<pathToFile>`

Note the `<extensionID>` is a unique identifier that the extension system generates for each extension. You can see the IDs for all your loaded extensions by going to the URL **chrome://extensions**. The `<pathToFile>` is the location of the file under the extension's top folder; it's the same as the relative URL.

...

Changing background image in CSS:

> `#id` { background-image:
>   url("`chrome-extension://<extensionID>/<pathToFile>`"); }

Changing background image in CSS through JavaScript:

> document.getElementById('`id`').style.backgroundImage =
>   "url('chrome-extension://`<extensionID>`/`<pathToFile>`')");

Changing background image in CSS through jQuery:

> $("`#id`").css("background-image",
>   "url('chrome-extension://`<extensionID>`/`<pathToFile>`')");

Answer (score 2):

we can use the Predefined messages of Chrome extensions.
[Predefined messages](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/i18n/#overview-predefined)

```css
body {
  background-image:url('chrome-extension://__MSG_@@extension_id__/background.png');
}
```

Comment: Note, this does not work for fonts

Answer (score 0):

For manifest v3, there are some modifications:

1. `chrome.extension.getUrl()` -> `chrome.runtime.getUrl()`
2. "web_accessible_resources" -> "web_accessible_resources.resources"
3. fill in "web_accessible_resources.matches"

2, 3 like this:

```json
"web_accessible_resources": [{
  "resources": ["images/logo.png"],
  "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
}],
```

reference:

- https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/intro/mv3-migration/#web-accessible-resources

Answer (score 0):

Those answers above are great but your extension gets a new id every time it gets installed, so putting the id manually doesn't work if you gonna make it public at some point.

Here's my solution using manifest v.3:

```
//Get the url from some file within your extension's folder and store it on a global variable
var url = chrome.runtime.getURL('my_extension/img/Icon.svg');

//Take off the last part from the url string
url = url.replace('img/Icon.svg', '');
```

Now replace the src attribute for a custom one on every img tag and keep the file path as it's value like this:

```
<img ref-file="img/IconStop.svg" alt="">
```

Then run this function after loading the html:

```
loadImgs = function () {
    $("img[ref-file]").each(function() {
        var ref_file = $(this).attr('ref-file');
        url = url + ref_file;
        $(this).attr('src', url);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me in a Chrome extension built in Vue.js
The logo was stored in **/public/images/logo.png** and my components in **/src/components/shared/logo.vue**

```
<template>
  <img :src="logoURL" alt="Logo" />
</template>
<script>
export default {
    computed: {
        logoURL() {
            return chrome.runtime.getURL("images/logo.png");
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 3
}
```