# Chrome Extension - Cannot Load Images With CSS; Base64?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am having trouble problems trying to get my extension to work. I am trying to load an image with CSS but Chrome is not displaying it. I saw another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3559781/google-chrome-extensions-cant-load-local-images-with-css) that described my problem, and the solution was to use [base64](http://www.motobit.com/util/base64-decoder-encoder.asp). The example provided was not detailed enough for me to understand. Can someone please provide a more detailed example, or perhaps offer an alternative to base64?

```
body{ background-image:url(face.png); }

body { background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,iVB...); }
```

Comment: Where is this image (and the stylesheet that uses it) meant to be displayed? Where is face.png served from?

Answer (score 1):

Go to http://www.motobit.com/util/base64-decoder-encoder.asp

Upload your image file by browsing (below 'or select a file to convert to a Base64 string').

Connvert to base64. Copy the generated string and put it in your css.

e.g. If base64 encode of your image is : "9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEASABIAAD/4gv4SUNDX1BST0ZJTEUAAQEAAAvoAAAAAAIAAABtbnRyUkdC"

put,

body { 
background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEASABIAAD/4gv4SUNDX1BST0ZJTEUAAQEAAAvoAAAAAAIAAABtbnRyUkdC); 
}