# Chrome Ext and JQuery Resources must be listed in the web_accessible_resources manifest key in order to be loaded by pages outside the extension

Tags: jquery-ui, google-chrome-extension

I have Chrome extension that loads jquery-1.8.3.min.js and jquery-ui.js and jquery-ui-base64.css into the content script .
i use them in the content script **NOT** background script .
i set the configuration ( i think ) right but when i see in the console i getting errors 
i can see the icons in the windows just fine , but i still getting the errors in the Chrome window.
is it a bug in chrome im using version 23.0.1271.95 m?

this is the manifist :

```
{
"name":"Sample communication from content to background",
"description":"This is a sample for Simulating communication from content to background",
"manifest_version":2,
"version":"2",
"background":{
    "scripts":["background.js"]
},
"content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["jquery-1.8.3.min.js","jquery-ui.js","client.js"],
      "run_at":"document_end",
      "all_frames": true,
      "css":["jquery-ui-base64.css"]
    }
  ],
"web_accessible_resources": [
    "client.js","jquery-1.8.3.min.js","jquery-ui.js","jquery-ui-base64.css",
    "images/ui-bg_flat_0_aaaaaa_40x100.png",
    "images/ui-bg_flat_75_ffffff_40x100.png",
    "images/ui-bg_glass_55_fbf9ee_1x400.png",
    "images/ui-bg_glass_65_ffffff_1x400.png",
    "images/ui-bg_glass_75_dadada_1x400.png",
    "images/ui-bg_glass_75_e6e6e6_1x400.png",
    "images/ui-bg_glass_95_fef1ec_1x400.png",
    "images/ui-bg_highlight-soft_75_cccccc_1x100.png",
    "images/ui-icons_222222_256x240.png",
    "images/ui-icons_2e83ff_256x240.png",
    "images/ui-icons_454545_256x240.png",
    "images/ui-icons_888888_256x240.png",
    "images/ui-icons_cd0a0a_256x240.png"
  ],
"permissions": [ 
        "unlimitedStorage",
        "http://*/",
        "<all_urls>",
        "tabs"
   ]
}
```

in the jquery-ui-base64.css i changed all the imags url load to something like this :

```
 url(chrome-extension://__MSG_@@extension_id__/chrome-extension://__MSG_@@extension_id__/images/ui-bg_flat_75_ffffff_40x100.png) 
url(chrome-extension://__MSG_@@extension_id__/chrome-extension://__MSG_@@extension_id__/images/ui-bg_highlight-soft_75_cccccc_1x100.png)
```

but still im getting the errors:

```
Denying load of chrome-extension://mmoccjinakdjcmhjdjghhjnihbfkkgkp/chrome-extension://mmoccjinakdjcmhjdjghhjnihbfkkgkp/images/ui-bg_flat_75_ffffff_40x100.png. Resources must be listed in the web_accessible_resources manifest key in order to be loaded by pages outside the extension.
Denying load of chrome-extension://mmoccjinakdjcmhjdjghhjnihbfkkgkp/chrome-extension://mmoccjinakdjcmhjdjghhjnihbfkkgkp/images/ui-bg_highlight-soft_75_cccccc_1x100.png. Resources must be listed in the web_accessible_resources manifest key in order to be loaded by pages outside the extension.
```

the images are there in the images dir and i can see the icons in the JQuery dialog i created.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT 1)**

The following code works for all background\extension related DOM and css

***manifest.json***

*Simple json structure with all permissions defined*

```
{
"name": "My extension",
"version": "1.0",
"permissions": [
    "http://*/*", "tabs", "https://*/*"
],
"browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.jpg",
    "default_popup":"popup.html"
},
"manifest_version": 2
}
```

***popup.html***

*Linked style sheet for Browser action Popup*

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css"></link>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

***styles.css***

*used url() for image path*

```
body{
    width : 500px;
    height: 500px;
    background-image: url('img/icon.jpg');
}
```

Let me know if it still fails

[image]

> **EDIT 2)**

For Injecting Images through content stuff

**Solution a)**

Using [this converter](http://webcodertools.com/imagetobase64converter), you convert your image to base64 strings and you can use them as

> {    background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw ........ };

**Solution b)**

The following code will not work because

```
{
background-image:url(chrome.extension.getURL('img/icon.jpg'));
}
```

[chrome.extension.getURL()](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/extension.html#method-getURL) is undefined for css.

So, i used js for injection of background-images\any image URL's(Because they have dynamic URL's)

***manifest.json***

*Simple json structure with all permissions defined for content scripts and css*

```
{
"name": "My extension",
"version": "1.0",
"permissions": [
    "http://*/*", "tabs", "https://*/*"
],
 "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js":["content.js"],
      "css": ["styles.css"]
    }
  ],
"web_accessible_resources": [
    "img/icon.jpg"
],  
"manifest_version": 2
}
```

***content.js***

*As a trivial use case prepared a div and added background Image property*

```
var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
newdiv.setAttribute("id", "moot450");
document.body.appendChild(newdiv);
document.getElementById('moot450').style.backgroundImage = "url(" + chrome.extension.getURL('img/icon.jpg') + ")";
```

***styles.css***

*injected another css for refining injected div*

```
#moot450{
    position:absolute; 
    width:500px;
    height:500px;
    /*background-image:url(chrome-extension://faaligkhohdchiijdkcokpefpancidoo/img/icon.jpg);*/
}
```

**OUTPUT**

*Screen shot taken from Google Page after injection*

[image]

Let me know if you need more information or if it fails.

Comment: well i forgat to say its all in content script not backgound

Comment: @user63898: I have updated my suggestions in `edit 2)` let me know your views

Comment: @user63898 For reference this question is related to this question.. http://stackoverflow.com/q/13669762/189093 ... but that doesnt matter as the answer is rather simple... change `url(chrome-extension://__MSG_@@extension_id__/chrome-extension://__MSG_@@extension_id__/images/ui-bg_flat_75_ffffff_40x100.png) ` to `url(chrome-extension://__MSG_@@extension_id__/images/ui-bg_flat_75_ffffff_40x100.png)` and the other one like wise (not enoguh characters to put it in here).  Notice the difference?  You put `chrome-extension://__MSG_@@extension_id__` in the url twice for some reason.

Comment: @PAEz thanks allot ! how can i give you upvote or something here for the answer ?

Comment: @user63898 its cool dont worry bout the points, just glad to help.