# Chrome-extension URL match patterns:Why rules are not working for Google.com?

Tags: ajax, google-chrome, iframe, google-chrome-extension, google-search

I'm making an extension to customize Google' homepage background.So I write some match rules in manifest like this:

```
"content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["https://www.google.com/", "http://www.google.com/"],
      "js": ["static/js/jquery.js", "static/js/contentscript.js"]
    }
],
```

and some scripts in `contentscript.js`:

```
var imgURL = chrome.extension.getURL("static/images/bg.jpg");
$('body').css('background-image', 'url(' + imgURL + ')');
```

The script works fine for [https://www.google.com](https://www.google.com/), but when I try to search something ,the page jumps to [https://www.google.com/#newwindow=1&sclient=psy-ab&q=Google&oq=Google&gs_l=hp.3..35i39l2j0i20l2j0l6.4788.5717.2.5939.5.3.2.0.0.0.142.397.0j3.3.0....0.0..1c.1.20.hp.xCFVga8gVZU&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.49784469%2Cd.dGI%2Cpv.xjs.s.en_US.MpiVkF51mpA.O&fp=806ba48f5b2ed550&biw=1920&bih=963](https://www.google.com/#newwindow=1&sclient=psy-ab&q=Google&oq=Google&gs_l=hp.3..35i39l2j0i20l2j0l6.4788.5717.2.5939.5.3.2.0.0.0.142.397.0j3.3.0....0.0..1c.1.20.hp.xCFVga8gVZU&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.49784469,d.dGI,pv.xjs.s.en_US.MpiVkF51mpA.O&fp=806ba48f5b2ed550&biw=1920&bih=963)

But the script is **still** working after the jumping! And if I paste the long url in a new tab directly, it **won't** work!

I think it should be related with iframe or Ajax or something else. Could someone give some more details? And how can I prevent scripts from running after the url changed?

Comment: I'm not sure why it *isn't* loading when you directly visit the search page. I've never inspected it too closely, but it seems Google is a bit tricky: when you do a search from their main page, I don't think they ever actually load a new page. They just heavily edit the DOM of the existing page to include search results (and use the [history API](http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html) to allow you to use your back button, I think). Thus, the results page is not a new page, so your content script is still loaded.

Comment: What I see is that the search result page had a obvious reloading action,quite different from Github that changes its URL without reloading.

Comment: PS. Come on, you don't need jQuery for something as trivial as changing the background image: `document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + chrome.extension.getURL("static/images/bg.jpg") + ')';` does the same thing and saves you many bytes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to apply a style to Google's home page, just use a selector which is very specific to Google's homepage. With the Inspector, I quickly discovered that the `<body>` tag at the homepage has a class "hp". This class does not show up in search results.

Drop your JavaScript code, and use

#### Part of `manifest.json`

```js
"content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["*://www.google.com/*"],
      "css": ["my-google-style.css"]
    }
],
"web_accessible_resources": [
    "static/images/bg.jpg"
],
```

- The first wildcard, `*`, means "http" and "https".
- The added wildcard at the end does not matter, because the "homepage" requirement is enforced in the next stylesheet.
- The [`"web_accessible_resources"`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest.html#web_accessible_resources) key is necessary if you want to display the image in an external (=non-extension) page.

#### `my-google-style.css`

```css
body.hp {
    background-image: url("chrome-extension://__MSG_@@extension_id__/static/images/bg.jpg");
}
```

---

The first part of my answer is the recommendation for your case. In general, if you want to catch *every* (scripted and user-initiated) URL change, including but not limited to:

- `history.pushState` / `history.replaceState`
- `location.hash = '...';`
- User goes back / forward (and changes hash / history state)

... then you need to use the [`chrome.webNavigation`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation.html) API in the background/event page, in particular the [`onHistoryStateUpdated`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation.html#event-onHistoryStateUpdated) and/or [`onReferenceFragmentUpdated`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation.html#event-onReferenceFragmentUpdated) events. In response to these events, you'll either [send a message](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html) or execute a [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html#pi).

If you only expect rewrites of the reference fragment (aka location hash), then there's no need for the `webNavigation` API. The implementation will be simplier, as you only need to listen to the global `hashchange` event in the content script.

Comment: Tks for ur long answer. BTW, I think the prefix chrome-extension://__MSG_@@extension_id__/ is necessary in manifest v2,  otherwise the injection will be "google.com/static/images/bg.jpg" :-)

Comment: @Sam URLs within stylesheet are resolved relative to the style sheet. Last time I checked, there was no need to add these images to the `web_accessible_resources` section of the manifest file to get it to work.

Comment: I still failed. 
The relative path is recognized as Google's, not my extension, 
so the style injection result I see at the chrome developer tools is "google.com/static/images/bg.jpg". 
Check it here:`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3559781/google-chrome-extensions-cant-load-local-images-with-css/8864212#8864212`

Comment: @Sam I've revised my answer, see the revision history to see what's different.

Answer (score -1):

You need to include a wildcard `*` to your `matches` like so:

```
"content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["https://www.google.com/*", "http://www.google.com/*"],
      "js": ["static/js/jquery.js", "static/js/contentscript.js"]
    }
],
```

Comment: If so,every link which started with `https://www.google.com/` will be injected.I just mean the Google Homepage.

Comment: Could you add a check with `window.onhashchange` so that, if `window.document.location.href != "https://www.google.com/" && window.document.location.href != "http://www.google.com/"`, revert your code's changes? Also see http://stackoverflow.com/a/2162174/206410