# How to distinguish the search from Omnibox and Google in a Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-search

I am writing a Chrome extension try to distinguish the search made by Omnibox (address bar) and google.com.

I notice that if I make a search directly from google, the url looks like https://www.google.com/#q=example. While if I search from the Omnibox, the url looks like https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=example

I can distinguish the difference from the url here. But if I make another search in the page opened by Ominbox, it still shows https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=example

Then I am not able to distinguish the difference here.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: There are probably many ways to achieve this, and because of that we need an idea of how your code works.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/17930656/1587329, you can use [`onReferenceFragmentUpdated`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation.html#event-onReferenceFragmentUpdated). The only time it has fired for me is when the omnibox is finally updated. (the `onHistoryStatusUpdate` event does not contain the final `#...` ref field)

---

**Older solution**:
The search via omnibox does not fire a [`WebRequest`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest).

Thus, you could create a `WebRequestListener`, say at `onBeforeRequest`, and check later if such a listener was triggered.