# Chrome Extension Connect Scripts - referencing resources

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm making my first Chrome extension, and I've run into a little problem. I'm using content scripts to inject some javascript and css into a page, which is working great. However I'm running into an issue, where some of the css references images. I have these images in the folder with the extension, but when the css is injected, all of the relative references don't work, and instead are attempting to find those resources on the site I'm injecting the code into.

Is there a way I can have my content script also reference images or other resources, or should I approach this in a different way?

To be more specific, should it be needed, I'm attempting to use the jquery fancybox, which uses a few image resources to function. The console will show this message:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

when attempting to load the resources because it's looking on the hosting server, not in my extension folder. How can I reference resources included in my extension?

Answer (score 1):

Found this information here: [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3559781/google-chrome-extensions-cant-load-local-images-with-css)

Your content scripts must load the images through `chrome.extension.getURL(path of image);`

Hope this helps