# How to add a file from my filesystem to chrome inspect element dev tools?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to edit a webpage I have online access to using inspect element, and chrome developer web tools.

I would like to add an image from my local filesystem to the webpage. How might I do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Open inspect element, and head over to the `Sources` tab.
Now click on the `Filesystem` tab (within `Sources`), next to `Page`.

As shown below, you'll see a button that says, `Add folder to workspace`. Click it, and add the folder containing the file you want to add to the page.

[image: Click Add folder to workspace]

Now if you right-click on the image, you'll see that you can get a data URI representing it.

You could use that in place of a link in an `img` tag's `src`, like so:
`<img src="YOUR DATA URI">`

Comment: Excellent answer! Just a hint: If you add the folder, chrome might ask you if you give permission to add it in a top bar (I didn't notice that and thought this answer doesn't work any longer).

Answer (score 0):

There is a newer chrome method called "Local Overrides" which enables persisting objects during inspector sessions described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63656686/470517