# custom checkbox css for a chrome extension

Tags: css, google-chrome-extension

I really want to use a custom checkbox design for my checkboxes inside of my chrome extension but it just doesn't seem to work. My guess is that there is some sort of interference with the background image of the checkbox because all of the css seems to be applied except for the background.

The css code I'm using for the checkboxes is from iCheck:

```
.icheckbox_flat-blue,
.iradio_flat-blue {
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background: url(blue.png) no-repeat;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.icheckbox_flat-blue {
    background-position: 0 0;
}
    .icheckbox_flat-blue.checked {
        background-position: -22px 0;
    }
    .icheckbox_flat-blue.disabled {
        background-position: -44px 0;
        cursor: default;
    }
    .icheckbox_flat-blue.checked.disabled {
        background-position: -66px 0;
    }

.iradio_flat-blue {
    background-position: -88px 0;
}
    .iradio_flat-blue.checked {
        background-position: -110px 0;
    }
    .iradio_flat-blue.disabled {
        background-position: -132px 0;
        cursor: default;
    }
    .iradio_flat-blue.checked.disabled {
        background-position: -154px 0;
    }
```

and `blue.png` looks like this:

[image]

On a regular site this html and css works fine but once transferred into a chrome extension it doesn't. Is there something I'm doing wrong? How do I get a custom checkbox design?

Comment: Also covered here http://stackoverflow.com/q/3559781/2213940

Comment: @ZigMandel We don't know for sure if it is used in a content script.

Comment: Hopefully asker will clarify but it certainly seems like it. Otherwise the background css would work as he says does outside the extension.

Answer (score -1):

The `background-image` has to be in quotes:

```
background: url("blue.png") no-repeat;
```

Answer (score -2):

Sorry, I have answered my own question. I still don't honestly know what the problem was but I switched away from using iCheck and decided to create my own code for editing the checkbox.

Sorry for wasting anyones time.

Comment: No. You have not _answered_ the question.