# web accessible resources stopped recognising my image

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, resources, manifest

I get this error:

> Denying load of
>   chrome-extension://boelmimalaoomchodajlpmibbopknpoh/images/Alert.png/.
>   Resources must be listed in the web_accessible_resources manifest key
>   in order to be loaded by pages outside the extension.

even though in my manifest file i have this:

```
"web_accessible_resources": [
  "images/Alert.png"
]
```

It was working fine half an hour ago, I didn't change anything in the manifest file or where the image is stored and it just stopped working now.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using the image in css or JS properly? Like this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3559781/google-chrome-extensions-cant-load-local-images-with-css

Comment: @gui47 `var imgSrc = chrome.runtime.getURL("images/Alert.png")` JS for getting the image source, like i said, this worked before

Comment: It's weird. Have you tried to use `var imgSrc = chrome.extension.getURL("images/Alert.png")` instead?

Comment: @gui47 just tried that - exact same thing happens, doesn't work

Comment: U have reloaded the extension and refreshed the page, right?

Comment: @gui47 yep, reloaded everything several times, on several different pages, same thing everytime

Comment: As far as I know, it sounds a bug to me now. Maybe you can post more codes or file it on [crbug.com](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list)

Comment: Somehow there is a `/` getting added to the image URL. Make sure the HTML tag isn't weird.

Comment: Preemptively voting to close as a typo, abraham's observation is most probably correct.

Comment: yeah, abraham was right, I just can't see lol  fixed it now