# Using bootstrap.css as content script distorts gmail UI?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome-extension

I am injecting a  `bootstrap` modal in gmail. For that I need `bootstrap.css`. I included it in under `content_scripts` in `manifest.json`

```
"content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["https://mail.google.com/*"],
      "css":["lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
             "css/modal.css"
             ],
      "js": [ "lib/jquery/jquery.min.js",
              "lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
             ],
    "run_at":"document_end"
    }
```

But it reduces the font size and distorts menu bar

[image]

When i remove the css file , everything looks fine.

**One more issue is** : `bootstrap` uses glyphicons but they are not shown because extension look for these fonts under :

```
https://mail.google.com/mail/u/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf

https://mail.google.com/mail/u/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff
```

I have added these files as `web_accessible_resources` too. But they still dont work

Comment: 1. Try injecting it in an iframe 2. Alternatively modify the CSS to limit the elements' specificity by prepending all selectors in the rules with your modal id 3. The font urls should point to your extension path

Comment: First option does not sound feasible. For font , would i have to use chrome.extension.getURL() where icons are referenced??

Comment: Try using the special ids directly in CSS as shown in the linked answer for [Google Chrome Extensions - Can't load local images with CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8864212).

Comment: Thanks. Fonts are now working. For the distorted ui i was thinking of using scoped style. Would that work?

Comment: that's something you [can google easily](https://google.com/#q=css+style+scoped+browser+support), in short: no.

Comment: I tried but it didn't work

Comment: for the fonts. bootstrap seems to be loading after your styles and thus overriding them.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Having the same problem, where the injected CSS is affecting the page, where I really only want it to apply to my modal and it's contents.

Comment: @theVinchi Yes I resolved it using iframe, it worked perfectly fine.

Comment: @Sid you injected an iframe into the page body and then included your bootstrap CSS in the iframe, right? So your modal will be running in the iframe, right? What is the value of the "src" attribute you use when creating the iframe?

Comment: @theVinchi Value of src attribute is path to your html(not the drive path), i.e chrome.extension.getURL("path to html inside extension root directory"); For more info : https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources