# Angluar2 routing in chrome extension

Tags: angular, google-chrome-extension, angular2-routing

I am creating chrome extension using angular2. The app is compiled using webpack. The problem is that when I added routing in my app, suddenly my html, can't find files in directories that exist with wanted files...

This is my source map that chrome shows:

[image]

this is my html:

```
<div class="app-main-component">
    <img src="../images/logo-cw-white.png">
</div>
```

This is my dev source map (app is running using dist folder, that is made when compiled with webpack):

[image]

My routing file:

```
import { NgModule }             from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { HelloAgainComponent } from './app/hello-again.component';
import { AppComponent} from './app/app.component'
import { AppMainComponent} from './app/app-main.component'

const routes: Routes = [  
  { 
    path: '**', 
    component: AppMainComponent,
    children: [
      { 
        path: 'again', 
        component: HelloAgainComponent 
      },
    ]
   }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes) ],
  exports: [ RouterModule ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

before I created routing file the image was found by html, but know it does not find it....

Error:
*Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND : chrome-extension://xyxyx/src/dist/images/logo-cw-white.png*

As I understand my routing directories are incorrect... Can someone please help me fix this??

Comment: Could be caused by the fact that relative paths in Chrome extensions are resolved from the root directory of the extension regardless of your `.` in the path. WebExtensions IIRC only accept relative paths that start with `/` to indicate this behavior explicitly.

Comment: Also it may be caused by an invalid chrome extension configuration (inside manifest.json). You need to specify **"web_accessible_resources"** in manifest.json. Please, refer to this question for more info  [Google Chrome Extensions - Can't load local images with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3559781/google-chrome-extensions-cant-load-local-images-with-css).

Answer (score 4):

I was affected by the similar issue using Angular 4.4

The solution was pretty easy (thanks to this answer [Angular 2 router no base href set](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42356965/2900278)).
You just need to use **HashLocationStrategy**.

Basically, what it does - it uses a hash strategy for routing.
For example, a chrome extension url may look like (and it blows up the standard angular routing because it doesn't have a normal http:domain.com/ url):

*chrome://extension-xxx/*

After enabling HashLocationStrategy angular will rely on hash inside the url:

*chrome://extension-xxx/**#**/*

```
import { LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)
  ],
  providers: [
    { provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: it works but only half. When you reload the page, you get 404. Any solution to this problem?

Comment: Hi, @VikasGautam. It works fine for me and I hadn't got 404. Probably, it may require setting `<base href="/">` in your **popup.html**, but I am not sure.

Answer (score 3):

I came across the same problem and used HashLocationStrategy to get around it. Happiness didn't last long as I noticed that when I refresh my webpage. I get 404 again.

Base Href: /dist/app/

So generally,
1. Browser go to chrome-extension://hkmmlaghihcdhmpodgfnkkjbmecahifc/dist/app/index.html
2. Angular routing with HashLocationStrategy kicks in and changes url to chrome-extension://hkmmlaghihcdhmpodgfnkkjbmecahifc/dist/app/#/browse
The app works at this point.
3. I refresh the page and get 404 as browser is trying to go to chrome-extension://hkmmlaghihcdhmpodgfnkkjbmecahifc/dist/app/#/browse straight without loading the app/index.html

Do you have any solutions?

**Solution:-**
I changed base href to dist/app/index.html. Now its working fine.
Reason? well, now #/browse gets appended after dist/app/index.html which allows my bundle.js to load and later on angular loads #/browse.

Hope it saves someone's time especially the people who are developing chrome extensions using angular2+ (my angular version is 5) where server is built into chrome and developer has no control over it.