# Is it possible to do modern style clean routes on a Chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3, web-extension

I have a Chrome extension / web extension that occasionally opens content in new tabs. For example, opening the URL `extension://lijpcppdcclkfneghlldocanomgeabja/index.html` in a new tab, opens the `index.html` which is a file inside my extension.

**Is there a way to do catchall routing?** For example, route the URL `extension://lijpcppdcclkfneghlldocanomgeabja/items/(some integer)`  to a particular page inside the extension?

I have looked in [the docs](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/) and can't seem to find a mention of any mechanism that allows for an abstraction between extension URL and the files loaded. This seems very odd for a currently maintained platform.

I did find [this example of a user using 2010-style `#anchor` URL routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42390267/angluar2-routing-in-chrome-extension#:%7E:), but that is a workaround and produces ugly URLs.

Comment: You can use the standard [SW fetch event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerGlobalScope/fetch_event) in your `service_worker` script to serve these virtual URLs. Once the page is shown you can use `navigation` API and `history.replaceState`.